# A custom Linux installer

Tags: linux

Is it possible to create a custom linux installer which allows me to choose a very minimal installation which bascially includes a kernel, bootloader, basic networking/core utlities, shell and some of my own C++/Java cooked applications.

I am setting up a small cluster using a couple of old computers. I may have to often delete/re-create partitions and modify my application settings to match my requirements.

I tried both Ubuntu and Fedora and even went as far as using their remastering tools. The problem is they end-up installing packages unnecessary for my work and worse they actually startup during boot. Currently, I have scripts which will have to be downloaded to these machines to do the 'clean-up' work.

I even had a look at LFS (Linux from Scratch). It was just the thing I needed, but it had no associated installer with it. Tools for automating LFS installation like nALFS and jhalfs do not have good documentation and are unsitable for this kind of work.

It would be really good if I can make an installer iso file which will do everything in the first go itself, i.e. while installing linux. Is it possible to create such a linux installer? Are there any such ready-made tools?

Comment: https://fedorahosted.org/spin-kickstarts/browser/fedora-aos.ks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [ArchLinux](http://archlinux.org/), a clean and flexible linux distribution.

The installer only installs the basics (no X, just a root prompt) and allows you to customize from there.
`pacman -Sy bash-completion openssh`

It currently 7th on [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/), the highest ranking "non user friendly" linux.

- Very up to date (Rolling release)
- Great package manager (pacman)
- Lightweight and (technically) simple
- Configuration by editing text files (not for linux newbies)
- Easy to create your own packages.

For your setup I recommend creating an **system image** with [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or an other partition clone/restore tool.

After the restore you'll just have to change the hostname to use an unique one like "node21" or something.

Setup an [your own custom repository](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Custom_local_repository#Custom_local_repository) with your applications.

To update the nodes you can publish the new version of your package and use Archlinux's package manager to update the nodes.

This way you can use an "old" image and easily bring it up to date. Bypassing the whole custom installer problem.

Comment: While I was working on Zds's answer I gave a look at this. It sounds a bit more stream-lined. As for system image, without tickling my brain too much, I 'dd'd the root partition (which apparently contains /boot too) and bzip'd it on a usb-stick.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pick Linux distribution of your choice and configure it's installer to install only packages you want. Most Linux distributions already come in different flavors, so customizing what packages the installer installs is pretty mundane task.
   or
2. If you want *versions* of packages that are different from what any available Linux distribution offers, create your own distribution: http://www.gnewsense.org/Builder/HowToCreateYourOwnGNULinuxDistribution

Comment: That was an awesome fast answer. I'm looking at it right now. Thanks.

Comment: I read the link. It seemed good when I started, but as I read each step I realised that I will have to mirror some parts of Ubuntu repository. I'll try it anyway.

Comment: Tried it yesterday and the day before. Ended up mirroring a small amount of packages. But there is far more to go and a lot of scripts to run :(

Answer (score 1):

Many CD-Bootable systems start from HPA's [SYSLINUX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslinux) Suite.

Another popular answer is to start from [KNOPPIX](http://www.knoppix.org/).

Comment: SYSLINUX is fine for a boot-loader, but how about the actual installation? Knoppix or as a matter of fact many of those live disks out there have a tendencey to compete with each other trying to squeeze as much possible in as little space which is an overkill in my case.

Comment: @Eshan, since you sure sounded like you knew exactly what you wanted from an installed system, I figured you'd just have a tarball of files you wanted installed, then configure grub to boot it...

Comment: That's right. Only a small amount (2/3) packages will be added or removed apart from the base install. This of course will be the final stage. But before that I need to do some experiments to arrive at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I used SLAX to build bootable CD that did some simple installation work:

http://www.slax.org/

As I remember, I didn't spend much time customizing it.

Another option is to try SUSE online build service:

http://susestudio.com/

You can start your own or clone someone's else appliance from their gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Another distro that implements the minimal install and then user selected optional packages is
Jeoss (server oriented).

Non PAE kernel perfect for old hardware.

It can be installed from the net 100% controlled even by a serial console or remote SSH session

http://www.vercot.com/~jeoss/default.html